# How to load multiple data.js files to react js app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

so im working on some kind of project and i want to load or input multiple data.js files to my react js app. i have dataCPU.js, dataGPU.js, and so on maybe around 7. here is my code for reference

App.js

```
import Header from './components/Header';
import Main from './components/Main';
import Builder from './components/Builder';
import {useState} from 'react';
import dataRAM from './dataRAM';

function App() {
  const {products} = dataRAM;
  const [builderItems, setBuilderItems] = useState([]);
  const onAdd = (product) => {
    const exist = builderItems.find(x => x._id === product._id);
    if(exist){
      setBuilderItems(
        builderItems.map(x =>
           x._id === product._id ? {...exist, qty: exist.qty+1} : x
        )
      );
    }else{
      setBuilderItems([...builderItems, {...product, qty: 1}])
    }
  }
  const onRemove = (product) => {
    const exist = builderItems.find((x) => x._id === product._id);
    if(exist.qty === 1) {
      setBuilderItems(builderItems.filter((x) => x._id !== product._id));
    } else{
      setBuilderItems(
        builderItems.map(x =>
           x._id === product._id ? {...exist, qty: exist.qty-1} : x
        )
      );
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header countBuilderItems={builderItems.length}></Header>
      <div className = "row">
        <Main 
          onAdd={onAdd} products={products}>
        </Main>
        <Builder 
          onAdd={onAdd} 
          onRemove={onRemove} 
          builderItems = {builderItems}
          ></Builder>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

dataRAM.js

```
const dataRAM = {
    products: [
        {
            _id:'1', 
            name: 'Adata 4GB DDR4 2666 DIMM Desktop Memory',
            speed: '2666mhz',
            modules: '1x4gb DDR4',
            casLatency: 17,
            price: 1399,
            store: 'store-y',
            image: '/images/RAM/Adata-4GB-DDR4-2666-DIMM-Desktop-Memory.jpg'
        },
        {
            _id:'2', 
            name: 'Adata 8GB DDR4 2666 DIMM Desktop Memory',
            speed: '2666mhz',
            modules: '1x8gb DDR4',
            casLatency: 17,
            price: 2399,
            store: 'store-y',
            image: '/images/RAM/Adata-8GB-DDR4-2666-DIMM-Desktop-Memory.jpg'
        },
        {
            _id:'3', 
            name: 'Adata 16gb DDR4 2666 DIMM',
            speed: '2666mhz',
            modules: '1x16gb DDR4',
            casLatency: 17,
            price: 4299,
            store: 'store-y',
            image: '/images/RAM/Adata-16GB-DDR4-2666-DIMM-Desktop-Memory.jpg'
        },
        {
            _id:'4', 
            name: 'Adata 16GB XPG SPECTRIX D60G DDR4-3000 RGB DUAL PACK (8GBx2) Memory Module',
            speed: '3000mhz',
            modules: '2x8gb DDR4',
            casLatency: 17,
            price: 5499,
            store: 'store-y',
            image: '/images/RAM/Adata-16GB-XPG-SPECTRIX-D60G-DDR4-3000-RGB.jpg'
        },
        {
            _id:'5', 
            name: 'Adata 32GB DDR4 2666 DIMM AD4U2666732G19-RGN Desktop Memory',
            speed: '2666mhz',
            modules: '1x32gb DDR4',
            casLatency: 19,
            price: 7499,
            store: 'store-y',
            image: '/images/RAM/Adata-32GB-DDR4-2666-DIMM-Desktop-Memory.jpg'
       },
    ]
}

export default dataRAM;
```

i have different kind of data.js and i want to upload or input them into my react app can anyone enlighten me on how to do that? thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

just add the import statement for each of you Data.js files at the top of app.js like you have done for RAMData.js here `import dataRAM from './dataRAM';`

eg:

```
import dataCPU from './dataCPU';
import dataGPU from './dataGPU';
//etc
```

make sure to include the `export default <variableNameHere>` line at the bottom of the Data.js files or else your import statements will not work.

This also assumes that the data.js files are in the same directory as the app.js file.